# Is this query correct? SELECT s FROM Salesmen s WHERE s.dateOfEmployment < '26-06-2012' ORDER BY s.salepersonId ASC

Tags: sql, database

I am not sure how to query for a date and I have tried it without the  '  ' but it does not work. I was wonder if this is correct. Dateofemployment is a Date in the database and the date I put there is the date.

```
SELECT s
FROM Salesmen s
WHERE s.dateOfEmployment < '26-06-2012'
ORDER BY s.salepersonId ASC
```

Comment: Not clearly stated question ,but are you looking for ? `SELECT s.'dateOfEmployment' FROM Salesmen s WHERE s.dateOfEmployment < '26-06-2012' ORDER BY s.salepersonId ASC`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? - and what is type of `dateOfEmployment` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct and you **must** put the two quotes since `dateOfEmployment` is a date. However, be careful with the position of the day and the month and make sure that your query does what you want.

Comment: but it gives me no results even tho there should be a lot :/

Comment: Yes, you have to write `'26-06-2012'`. Try with a `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT s` and, again, make sure that your date format is the one you store into your database.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** assume there's a specific date format (dmy,ymd,mdy,etc.), always use the functions of your DBMS for writing dates instead of writing a string literal, e.g. TO_DATE in Oracle (and some others).

In best case you can use Standard SQL's date literals:

```
WHERE s.dateOfEmployment < DATE '2012-06-26'
```

Most DBMSes support it and there's no ambiguity because there's only one format allowed: `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

When you leave out the quotes, you have a simple arithmetic expression:  `26 - 06 - 2012`.  This is equal to something like `-1992`.  That is an integer and not a date, so presumably the comparison will either generate an error or at least never return true.

When putting dates in queries, you should use ISO standard format:  `YYYY-MM-DD`.  Most databases will accept the following:

```
WHERE s.dateOfEmployment < '2012-06-26'
```

In Oracle, you need to add `date` before the constant.